# sscanf trouble?

Tags: c++, c, scanf

```
long ip2long( char *ip )
{
    long ip2long = 0;

    char B1[4], B2[4], B3[4], B4[4];
    int D1, D2, D3, D4 = 0;

    sscanf(ip, "%s.%s.%s.%s", B1, B2, B3, B4);

    D1 = atoi(B1);
    D2 = atoi(B2);
    D3 = atoi(B3);
    D4 = atoi(B4);

    if(D1 > 255 || D2  > 255 || D3 > 255 || D4 > 255)
        return 0;

    ip2long = D1*256*256*256+D2*256*256+D3*256+D4;

    return ip2long;
}
```

input data: 127.1.1.2

Why D1 == 127, but D2, D3 and D4 == 0?

--- UPDATE ---
Now code is

```
unsigned long ip2long( char *ip )
{
    unsigned long ip2long = 0;
    unsigned int D1, D2, D3, D4 = 0;

    sscanf(ip, "%u.%u.%u.%u", &D1, &D2, &D3, &D4);

    if(D1 > 255 || D2  > 255 || D3 > 255 || D4 > 255)
        return 0;

    ip2long = D1*256*256*256+D2*256*256+D3*256+D4;

    return ip2long;
}
```

Di is ok, but there are another troubles: result for 127.1.1.2 is 2130772226 instead of 2130772225 and result for 195.98.157.132 is -1016947324...
Why?

--- Update 2 ---
Thats ok, there was %d instread %u.

Kornel Kisielewicz thank you for telling about inet_addr function :)

PS sorry for my bad english =\

Question closed.

Comment: Re Update: I put the numbers into my calculator and 2130772226  looks right.  The result won't fit in a 32-bit long without potentially using the sign bit / negative values.  You can either return an unsigned long, a longer signed value (e.g. `long long` if your compiler supports it), or live with weird negative value.  You still have other bugs (as per my answer).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As fizzer notes, `%s` consumes the entire string - in this case dangerously copying it past the end of S1.  There would have been a big clue if the sscanf() result had been compared to 4!  Don't assume things will work, especially when parsing input from outside the program.  `atoi` ignores trailing garbage, so even with the `%[^.]` string format which will stop at a period it will process garbage values like `192,3.2x.3.1` by ignoring `,3` and `x`.

fizzer's suggestion of `("...%d...", &D1...)` is a good start, but you must still compare the result to 4, otherwise invalid strings like "hello" would simply leave D1, D2, D3 and D4 unchanged.  Negative values would be accepted.  Note that only D4 is set to 0 - other values are not affected by the trailing `= 0` on that line and may contain old garbage values form the stack which may or may not get through the later check against 255.

Summarily:

```
unsigned long ip2ulong(char *ip)
{
    unsigned u1, u2, u3, u4;
    return sscanf(ip, "%u.%u.%u.%u", &u1, &u2, &u3, &u4) == 4 &&
           u1 <= 255 && u2 <= 255 && u3 <= 255 && u4 <= 255
           ? u1*256*256*256 + u2*256*256 + u3*256 + u4 : 0;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

The first %s consumes the entire input, then atoi only converts the initial digits.  Use %d instead, and pass in &D1, &D2, etc for the corresponding arguments.

Then consider using unsigned ints for the Di, %u for the format conversion, and unsigned long for the result. Long may be as narrow as 32 bits, and the resulting differences of sign may be surprising.

Answer (score 5):

%s behaviour is greedy -- it reads as much as it can. You can use %d to read numbers instead.

However, is there any reason why you not use the `inet_addr` function? It is available on [POSIX](http://www.unix.com/man-page/POSIX/3posix/inet_addr/) and [Windows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms738563%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: OS is Linux, what library may I include?